# Identifying the last payment transaction in subset with equal datetime

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am collecting payment data from bank accounts (both credit and debit) in Google Spreadsheets containing datetime of transaction, ammount of transaction, and actual balance after transaction. I use it to visualise the actual balance looking for maximum in datetime for each account. From time to time happens, that some payments are realised with the same datetime and the data is not processed chronologically (the order of payments is not real). I need to run a script on my spreadsheet which will identify the last payment analysing the ammounts, balances, and type (credit/debit) and will delete the balance data from preceding payments.

OR is it better (possible) do load data into BigQuery and write a query which will resolve this? What would you do?

Logic: If count of entries with the same value in "own_account_number" and "transaction_datetime" > 1, then compare "transaction_value", "balance" and "Type" to find the last transaction. (Note that "processed_datetime" is not in the same order as the transactions increased the balance of that particular account)

Thanks

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yykgk.jpg)

Comment: so, the only you need is to reorder your entries in the order described in "logic" section? can you just use native order (by multiple columns) features of spreadsheet?

Comment: Are you saying that `IF( line x has transaction=-10, balance= 200 ), THEN( get all lines y where balance = 210, get the y with latest datetime, and insert this y before line x)`? It would be helpful if there's a representative of what the data looks like.

Comment: If transactions from a 1 account can have the same datetime, the only way to determine the order is by comparing the amount and type against the balance as you've said. You could then delete the preceding payments but would not longer be able to sort if need be. I'd suggest explicitly adding a column to preserver this if need be.
Sorting may be somewhat difficult but possible in a few ways - [range sorting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181254?hl=en), [sort function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en), etc. Alternatively, do all the processing within an Apps script.

Comment: @daniel: the example is in hyperlink "Data Example" in the last row of the question

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: there are no other collumns that could help to sort the entries.

Comment: @Nicholas: thanks, I think I will preffer the Apps script, but I will not delete the whole entry, only the balance from those who are not identified as last.

Comment: That is in fact what I understood from our post. Once the entries have been sorted, removing even just the preceding balances would remove the ability for you to sort that range again and get the same order. I would simply advise adding an index column that essentially increments to keep the original order. You could then hide that column as its purely functional and doesn't present particularly meaningful information.

Comment: It helps if you can remove sensitive information and share a representative spreadsheet with the community, so five people trying to help you don't have to re-type the data five times.